# how to replace an image with another onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these characteristics of these two images

```
#image1{
     position:absolute;
    left:29%;
    top:40%;
    background-image: url("../imgdrag/activity1.png");
    width:63px;
    height:38px;
}
#image2{
     position:absolute;
    left:29%;
    top:40%;
    background-image: url("../imgdrag/activity1red.png");
    width:63px;
    height:38px;
}
```

How can I replace the image1 with the image2 when I click on a button using a function

Comment: Any html code please?

Comment: And what JavaScript/JQuery have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
// this with jQuery
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('#image1').attr('id', '#image2');
});
```

or

```
function change(){
    document.getElementById('#image1').setAttribute('id', '#image2');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of switching state with jQuery

```js
$('.replace').click(function(){
  
  $('.image-holder').toggleClass('active');

})
```

```css
#image1{
     position:absolute;
    left:29%;
    top:40%;
    background-image: url("../imgdrag/activity1.png");
    width:63px;
    height:38px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: blue;
}
#image2{
     position:absolute;
    left:29%;
    top:40%;
    background-image: url("../imgdrag/activity1red.png");
    width:63px;
    height:38px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: red;
}
.image-holder {
 position: relative;
}
.image-holder.active #image2{

   z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="replace">Replace</button>

<div class="image-holder">

 <div id="image1"></div>
 <div id="image2"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is to change your css to

```
    #image1 {
        position:absolute;
        left:29%;
        top:40%;
        background-image: url("../imgdrag/activity1.png");
        width:63px;
        height:38px;
    }

    #image1.active {
        background-image: url("../imgdrag/activity1red.png");
    }
```

then if you are using jquery just add the new 'active' class, and remember to check first if it already has it.

```
    $('button').on('click', function(e) {
      var img = $('#image1');
      if (!img.hasClass('active')) {
        img.addClass('active');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use addEventListner Like the below code:

```js
// Tempory you can use an hard coded to
const replaceImageSrc = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503023345310-bd7c1de61c7d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8aHVtYW58ZW58MHx8MHx8&w=1000&q=80"
// Replace Image
const image = document.getElementById('image');
// Replace button
const replaceBtn = document.getElementById('replace-img-btn');

const imagesReplace = (img) =>{
    if(img != ""){
        image.src=`${img}`
    }else{
        image.src=""
    }
}

replaceBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    imagesReplace(replaceImageSrc)
})
```

```css
/* Fonts */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@300&display=swap");

:root {
  --primary-color: rgb(26, 26, 26);
  --secondary-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
  --font-family: Nunito, sans-serif;
  --box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 1px 1px 3px 0px inset, rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.5) -1px -1px 3px 1px inset;;
  --all-transition: transform ease-in-out 0.3s 0s;
}

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: var(--font-family);
}

.main-content{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container{
    width: 550px;
    height: 250px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
}

.img-container{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.img-container>img{
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.container>button{
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    color: var(--secondary-color);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: var(--all-transition);
}

/* Animation */
.container>button:hover{
    transform: scale(1.08);
}

.container>button:active{
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
    color: var(--primary-color);
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 1px solid var(--secondary-color);
}
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>codedamn HTML Playground</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main-content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="img-container">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541963463532-d68292c34b19?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8Mnx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80" id="image" alt="">
                </div>
    <button type="button" name="replace-img-btn" id="replace-img-btn">Replace Image</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```